# Materialized view on firebase events data in big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have a table in bigquery which fetches data from my firebase events analytics. The table is made in such a way that it appears to create a new table based on the date. But inside the databaseUI it appears as a single table. It changes when I click on it.

For example: Today's table name would be `‘tablename’_<today’s date>` and when I use the filter option  available in the big query UI for this particular table type. The name changes to `‘tablename'_'selecteddate'`.

I want to create a materialized view on the complete/ combine table of all dates. Not just on a table with a particular date.

How can I do it? Can someone please guide me?

The columns I want in Materialized View is even_date, event_name, event_params( key and value) , count of event_params (of key and value both).

I am unable to find a way. So is it possible?
Thank you